# Pypsark: Convert two array type columns to a single column of type ArrayType(Struct())

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Here is sample data:

```
id sub_id       score      
A  [1, 4]   [0.9, 0.2]
B  [5, 7]   [0.1, 0.5]
```

I'd like my resulting column to look like this:

```
id sub_id       score        result
A  [1, 4]   [0.9, 0.2]   [Struct{id = 1, score = 0.9}, Struct{id = 4 , score = 0.2}]
B  [5, 7]   [0.1, 0.5]   [Struct{id = 5, score = 0.1}, Struct{id = 7 , score = 0.5}]
```

The only way I know how to do this is to:

1. Explode both columns
2. Create a struct of both exploded columns
3. Group by `id` to create the `result` column.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip.html?highlight=arrays_zip) function, zips two array columns and creates a array struct.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("A", [1, 4], [0.9, 0.2],),
        ("B", [5, 7], [0.1, 0.5],), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("id", "sub_id", "score", ))

result = df.withColumn("result", F.arrays_zip(F.col("sub_id").alias("id"), F.col("score")))

result.printSchema()

result.show()
```

### Output

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sub_id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- score: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = true)



+---+------+----------+--------------------+
| id|sub_id|     score|              result|
+---+------+----------+--------------------+
|  A|[1, 4]|[0.9, 0.2]|[{1, 0.9}, {4, 0.2}]|
|  B|[5, 7]|[0.1, 0.5]|[{5, 0.1}, {7, 0.5}]|
+---+------+----------+--------------------+
```